# How to send a value from DAO back to Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, dao

I have a problem on how to proceed.
User enter email and clicks forgot password.
Then the servlet will call the Dao to check whether email exists or not and if it exists Dao will reset the password.
I want that Dao to send reset password back to servlet and redirect another servlet to send email back to user with reset password. Can anyone explain me how can I do that?

Below is my CheckEmailForgotDao

```
public class CheckEmailForgotDao{

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/mywebapp";
String username = "root";
String password = "root";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?";

public boolean check(String uname) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, uname);

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

            String randomPassword = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
            String resetsql = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE email = ?";
            PreparedStatement resetst = con.prepareStatement(resetsql);
            resetst.setString(1, randomPassword);
            resetst.setString(2, uname);

            System.out.println(resetst);
            resetst.executeUpdate();

        }

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Below is My Servlet

```
@WebServlet("/forgotpassword")
public class ResetPasswordServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ResetPasswordServlet() {
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String recipient = request.getParameter("email");
    String uname = recipient;

    CheckEmailForgotDao dao = new CheckEmailForgotDao();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    if (dao.check(uname)) {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/SendEmailResetPassword").include(request, response);
        
    } else {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").include(request, response);
        out.println("<script>document.getElementById('err-forgot').innerHTML= 'Email does not exist!'; </script>");

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can do it. below is my code.

-ForgotpasswordServlet -> CheckEmailForgot

-CheckEmailForgot -> check email exists -> Reset Password ->

-ForgotpasswordServlet -ForgotpasswordServlet -> Query Password with Email -> EmailForgotDao

-EmailForgotDao -> SendEmail -> ForgotpasswordServlet -> Show Email Sent

```
@WebServlet("/forgotpassword")
public class ResetPasswordServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ResetPasswordServlet() {
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String recipient = request.getParameter("email");
    String uname = recipient;

    CheckEmailForgotDao dao = new CheckEmailForgotDao();

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     

    if (dao.check(uname)) {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/mywebapp";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1, uname);

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String newpassword = rs.getString(3);

                EmailForgotDao emaildao = new EmailForgotDao();
                if (emaildao.sendemailforgot(uname, newpassword)) {

                    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").include(request, response);
                    out.println(
                            "<script>document.getElementById('msg-forgot').innerHTML= 'Reset password sent!'; </script>");

                }
            } else {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").include(request, response);
                out.println(
                        "<script>document.getElementById('msg-forgot').innerHTML= 'Error!'; </script>");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").include(request, response);
        out.println("<script>document.getElementById('msg-forgot').innerHTML= 'Email does not exist!'; 
 </script>");

    }

}
```

The above servlet use below CheckEmailForgotDao to check whether email exist or not.

1.If it exists this dao will reset password and return true.

2.If it does not exist this dao will return false and servlet will show email does not exits.

3.If below CheckEmailForgotDao return true, the servlet will query and get new reset password.

4.Then the servlet will use that to call another EmailForgotDao.

```
 public class CheckEmailForgotDao{
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/mywebapp";
 String username = "root";
 String password = "root";
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?";

 public boolean check(String uname) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, uname);

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

            String randomPassword = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
            String resetsql = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE email = 
  ?";
            PreparedStatement resetst = con.prepareStatement(resetsql);
            resetst.setString(1, randomPassword);
            resetst.setString(2, uname);

            System.out.println(resetst);
            resetst.executeUpdate();

        }

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
    }
```

Below EmailForgotDao will send email and return true. Then the servlet will show Reset Password Sent!

If it return false, due to errors, the servlet will show Error.

```
public class EmailForgotDao {

public static class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("youremail@gmail.com", 
"yourpassword");
    }
}



public boolean sendemailforgot(String uname, String newpassword) {

    String d_uname = "youremail@gmail.com";
    String d_password = "yourpassword";
    String d_host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int d_port = 465;

    String m_to = uname;
    String m_from = "soemoesmarttoy1@gmail.com";
    String m_subject = "Your Password has been reset";
    String m_text = "Hi your new password is " + newpassword;
    String abc = "text/plain";

    Properties props = new Properties();

    SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session ses = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(ses);

    try {
        msg.setContent(m_text, abc);
        msg.setSubject(m_subject);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(m_from));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));

        Transport transport = ses.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(d_host, d_port, d_uname, d_password);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        
    }
    
    return false;
}
}
```